# Why does G==G return false?

Tags: string, variables, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using the Unity Game Engine, and I have run into a problem with some of my code.

```
function NoteDecision(n :String) {
    Debug.Log("-"+n+"-"); // This is returning -G- which means its just "G"
    Debug.Log(n=="G");  // This is returning false, although n is G
    switch (n){
        case "G":
            Instantiate(GreenNote, SGreenNote.position, SGreenNote.rotation); break;
        case "R":
            Instantiate(RedNote, SRedNote.position, SRedNote.rotation); break;
        case "Y":
            Instantiate(YellowNote, SYellowNote.position, SYellowNote.rotation); break;
        case "B":
            Instantiate(BlueNote, SBlueNote.position, SBlueNote.rotation); break;
        case "O":
            Instantiate(OrangeNote, SOrangeNote.position, SOrangeNote.rotation); break;
        default : Debug.Log("There is a problem here...");
    }
}
```

So my code here hasnt changed, although I can tell you what has changed since it stopped working.

the variable n holds the second half of a string that I split, using String.Split(). Before, it held the second half before a comma.

```
Y,023.19592 // this is what it used to look like
023.19592,Y // this is what it looks like now
```

So anyway, here is the other snippet of code

```
note = lines[position].Split(","[0]); // this is where it gets split.
NoteDecision (note[1]);  // calling the function above.
```

So does anybody know what the problem is, or a solution?

Comment: The tag unity is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: @Curious Didnt I already add breaks at the end of each case? Maybe I didnt do it properly, can anybody help me though?

Comment: @indiv it looked so promising, but when I went and removed : String, it made no difference, and I am super stumped.. this should work!!

Comment: @indiv do I need to import something? its giving me the error Method not found

Comment: Make a better tag, Lex Li.  Unity3D doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but, shouldn't you write `break;` in the end of cases ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Debug.Log(n.Equals("G")); // this will return true
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer by providing a reasoning as to why the OP should use your proposed solution. A single sentence answer isn't really extremely helpful :)

Comment: This solution works for Android Java, but OP's code should work in Unity JavaScript, AFAIK.